# Delphi - ask twice for confirmation before closing the application

Tags: delphi

How can you prompt the user twice before closing the application on close query ? Just to make sure the user understands what he/she is about to do...

Comment: We need something more specific: to what are you coding for, are you using graphic libraries or is it a console application...

Comment: for i := 1 to 2 do NagUser;

Comment: How do you know he/she will understand with only two dialogs?

Comment: @TLama simpler `CanClose := ( MessageDlg('Are you sure you want to exit ?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYes ) and ( MessageDlg('Are you sure you were sure before :) ?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYes ` ; Bonus points go for `{$B+}` like in David's code

Comment: @SertacAkyuz i think we should ask for confirmation in a loop until N last questions would be the same. The larger is N, the more sure user gets. And we have to change default buttons and their order, so we'd be sure that it was not just a case of stuck keyboard or mouse. Additionally we can ask him for someone providing the surety

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM actually the TopicStarter is better to show the code, how he does ask for confirmation ONCE and then we'd hopefully can guide him to convert it into asking twice

Comment: Old Russian semi-linguistic joke. The pop-up windows asks "Wouldn't you refuse to format your hard drive ?" and the buttons are "Yes, i wouldn't" and "No, i wouldn't"

Comment: Have you ever come across a program that asks twice? The best programs don't ask at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan some programs even asked to key-in "YES". But those are exotic corner cases about really dangerous functions

Comment: Don't do that. User will just click Yes two times and hate you about that.

Comment: @user3181689 In all seriousness please ***do not*** do this. How would you feel if someone treated you as if you were stupid. Prompting once is bad enough - have faith that the user knows that closing the application will result in the application being closed. Prompting a second time is treating your users like morons - and they won't thank you for it. **Side note:** If you ever want to get your app certified as "Compatible with Windows", then a prompt when your app is supposed to close is a guaranteed **fail**.

Comment: I dont really know what is actually unclear to gentleman above.Its a simple strait forward question and has been answered by the gentleman Laurent PerrucheJ.If he understood me I dont know what 'their' problem is. What is actually 'unclear' to them,I really dont know. Do I need to write 'double prompt' instead of 'asking the confirmation twice' ???

Comment: @user3181689 I think everyone understood your question. However, as experienced software developers, we know it's a bad idea to do what you're asking. We're trying to discourage you from doing it **for your own benefit**.

Comment: didn't say I was going to use it,just wanted to know how how its done.just learning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just display two MessageDlg :

```
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
    CanClose := False;
    if MessageDlg('Are you sure ?', mtConfirmation, mbYesNo, 0) = mrYes then
    begin
        if MessageDlg('I think you underestimate the value of the question I just ask.' + #13 + #10 + 'Are you REALLY SURE you want to quit ?', mtConfirmation, mbYesNo, 0) = mrYes then
        begin
            CanClose := True;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

But please note that asking twice for confirmation is a total waste of time. Your users will end up clicking twice really fast, it will annoy them without enhancing your application "security"...

Comment: Just made my first 'Hello World' application in Delphi.... learning slowly....

Comment: why are you writing "CanClose := False;" at the start since you are about to trigger the message dialog anyway,I think???

Comment: Because CanClose is a parameter of the CloseQuery event which indicates if the application can be closed. I don't want to be rude, but please read a Delphi tutorial or something.

Comment: @user3181689 and what would happen with `CanClose` if the 1st dialog would return mrCancel or mrNo ? Either use my formula, that always give some value, or set some value yourself in some "invariant" code path warrantied to be executed.

Comment: ..and the 2nd prompt was like "...Hello? You ain't kidding? You really would close me that early???" and the special buttons

Comment: @Laurent PerrucheJ - can I ask simple noob questions on this site ? Or do you need to be an expert to ask a question? I do not know....I am new to this site ....

Comment: Sorry if I've offended you. Long story short: I set the "CanClose" parameter to False at the start of the procedure because this way i only have to set it to True once the two messages dialogs have been confirmed. Otherwise I will end up using @Arioch'The code, which I find more difficult to read, or setting the CanClose variable two times to False in <code>else</code> statements, which is also more difficult to read than my solution.

Comment: @user3181689 draw http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart for this method and consider that whatever path of th e three might happen, the CanClsoe should be se to some value. one or another. Then it becomes clear

Comment: +1, if only for the second message text.